# Applescript to disable screen saver through sending keystroke

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write an applescript that will disable the screen saver through sending a keystroke.  Something like sending a "shift key" pressed every 30 seconds.

I don't want to have the applescript actually disable the screen saver through system preferences.

Comment: http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/ perhaps ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the dictionary for the System Events app that's included with Applescript. You can access it from the AppleScript Editor:

> File > Open Dictionary... > System Events.app

There's a class called "screen saver preferences object" in there that should do what you need without having to script the GUI.

EDIT: Try setting the property "delay interval" of the object to 0 to disable the screensaver.

Comment: So basically: `tell app "System Events" to tell screen saver preferences to set delay interval to 0`. Display sleep might need to be disabled separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an on idle() handler, like this:

```
on idle
   -- Add your code here to keep the computer awake.
   return 1800 -- The number of seconds the script should delay before being idle again
end idle
```

but the screen saver prefs obj is a better tool. It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined **HOW** you want to solve the problem. I don't think that is the right approach. I think you should consider disabling and reenabling the screensaver.

This sets the Screen Saver to "never":

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to tell screen saver preferences to set delay interval to 0'
```

This sets the Screen Saver to 5 *minutes*:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to tell screen saver preferences to set delay interval to 300'
```

The interval value is in seconds even though the GUI shows minutes.

If your version of OSX has a slider in the Screen Saver System Preferences, the slider will update. Later versions, like Mountain Lion, have a dropdown with a few enumerated options. This does not update.